# Is the Shadow Broker the same character in Mass Effect 3 even if you haven't done the DLC?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-series

The Mass Effect 2 **Lair of the Shadow Broker** DLC sees Liara assume the role of the Shadow Broker.

Will Mass Effect 3 assume that she took over that role even if you don't import a character in which you completed that DLC?

Comment: Jesus Christ! Spoiler much???

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt It's been there since March.  Not much of a spoiler.

Comment: @fbueckert -1, that has absolutely 0 bearing on whether or not it's a spoiler, which this clearly is.

Comment: Sorry, I misread what happened here. Thanks for removing the spoiler from the title @DjangoReinhardt.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt: It's possible to hide all questions with a specific tag by using the [ignore tags feature](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/877/how-to-hide-questions-with-given-title). I'd suggest doing so on ME3 so you don't accidentally stumble across anymore spoilers :)

Comment: @Wipqozn Thanks, I've just tried to find this feature... but I couldn't see it? :(

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt: It's under the [prefs tab](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/4728) on your profile. That link will take you straight to it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have not played the Lair of the Shadow Broker, Liara is initially referred to as an information broker, like she was on Illium.

...until you get onto the privacy of the Normandy, where she has set up shop, and admits to Shepard that she has tracked down and usurped "the galaxy's most notorious information broker".

The dialog is a bit different if you actually helped her (via the DLC), but the outcome is the same regardless.

Comment: She does explicitly say she's the shadow broker too. I was actually wondering what the heck "the shadow broker" was.

Comment: @BenBrocka Ah, yes. "notorious information broker" are my words. There's not a question; Liara usurps the Shadow Broker nomatter what.

Comment: @Ben: The Shadow Broker is mentioned in several places in Mass Effect 2, even if you don't have the DLC.  IIRC there was even a mission to help someone *(was it Liara?)* gather information on the Shadow Broker, though you didn't actually catch the Shadow Broker or find out their identity.

Comment: And in ME1 as well (it's how you meet Tali).

Comment: The outcome isn't /quite/ the same. If Liara had to take down the previous Shadow Broker without your help, Feron doesn't survive.

Answer (score 2):

She is definitely the Shadow Broker in Mass Effect 3, regardless of if you played the DLC or not. I didn't play the DLC, but there were signs that she had become the Broker regardless. In one conversation with EDI, she lets slip that Liara has become the new shadow broker and also when you look at any war assets involving the shadow broker, there is usually a picture of Liara.